# Fragment ImageAdapter Listview not showing(listview)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to build Class FragmentChat it not work. But if i make ChatActivity(listview Adapter) it's work. I don't know problem because no error report. Program no error but Listview not show. Thank you for help me.

```
public class FragmentChat extends Fragment {

    private ListView listView;
    public ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot().child("AllRoom");

    private Room room;

    public static FragmentChat newInstance() {
        FragmentChat fragment = new FragmentChat();
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getContext().getTheme();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_chat, container, false);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(new FragmentChat.ImageAdapter(this));

        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
                Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                dataSnapshot.getValue();

                while (i.hasNext()){
                    DataSnapshot data = (DataSnapshot)i.next();
                    room = data.getValue(Room.class);
                    room.setKey(data.getKey());
                    rooms.add(room);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private FragmentChat context;


        public ImageAdapter(FragmentChat fragmentChat) {
            context = fragmentChat;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return rooms.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatroom, null);
            }

            // ColImgID
            TextView txtPosition = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgDesc);
            txtPosition.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            txtPosition.setText(rooms.get(position).getRoomName());

            ImageView btnChat = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListUserRoom);



            btnChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),ListUserRoom.class);
                    i.putExtra("key" , rooms.get(position).getKey());
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });

            return convertView;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting the onDataChange() callback ? Put some logs inside onDataChange() and follow with checking the size of rooms. It looks like your dataset (rooms) is empty, which may be happening due to the reason that the firebase callback is not getting called. Try to update the value from the Firebase backend for debugging.

Comment: Thank for comment. And dataset (rooms) is not empty, why not empty becasue if run RoomActivity it work and show rooms. but i want to work it Fragment is not work. so thank for debugging i will do it and update for you. @Prashant

Comment: Can you add your RoomActivity code ?